# Putting external properties into named queries

Tags: java, spring, jpa

Does anyone know of a way, if any, to put an external property into a jpa named query?

So for example:

```
@NamedQuery(name = "Test", query = "select t from ${table.name} t")
```

As opposed to:

```
 @NamedQuery(name = "Test", query = "select t from TableName t")
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Annotations are final hence they cannot be changed at runtime, so you cannot do that.

Answer (score 0):

You could define the native query at runtime instead of as a named query and translate the SQL string yourself.

Other solution would be to use some sort of pre compiler on your code, or use some sort of persistence unit event to post process your queries.  If you are using EclipseLink, you could use a SessionCustomizer for this, or a SessionEventListener to pre process SQL queries before they are executed.